# How to link a GUI Texture button to a script in Unity3d

Tags: c#, android, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I need some help to make a custom GUI Texture button, start a script on an 3d object when it is touched in Unity3d for android.

I have a GUI button to rotate a 3d model on pressed. The following (C#) script, I got is working O.K. when the button is created progrmaticaly:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RotateButtonBheaviour : MonoBehaviour {

private bool mIsRotated = false;
private bool mMustRotate = false;
private GameObject Cube;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Cube = GameObject.Find ("MarkerObject");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (mMustRotate && !mIsRotated) {
        //Rotate all models 45 degrees around X
        if (Cube != null) {
            GameObject modelUnderChipsTrackable = Cube.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
            modelUnderChipsTrackable.transform.RotateAround(new Vector3(1,0,0), Mathf.PI/3);

        }
        mIsRotated = true;
        mMustRotate = false;
    }


public Texture btnTexture1;

void OnGUI() {
    if (!btnTexture1) {
        Debug.LogError("Please assign a texture on the inspector");
        return;
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 120, 30), btnTexture1))
        if (!mIsRotated) {
            mMustRotate = true;
        }
```

I want instead of the button in the code to add my custom GUI Texture button (named OrbitBtn), so on touch, to start the 3d model rotating around its axe.

Please, give me some advice on how to achieve that functionality. Thank you all in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the texture btnTexture1, or you can click and drag-drop image files to your scripts, since you have declared btnTexture1 as public.

Or if you want to do the same in javascript here is the sample Code.

```
if(GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width*.85,Screen.height*0,width,width),Resources.Load("pause") as Texture))
{

//Button press action
}
```

So in this sample code, I am loading a image (pause.*) on to the button. Make sure that you have the image inside a folder called "Resources" in your asset folder.

Comment: Hello user3349513. Thanks for the tip. I am newbie to Unity...so, how to change the texture btnTexture1? My GUI Texture button is named "OrbitBtn". Do you mean to change "btnTexture1" to "OrbitBtn"?

Comment: No, it depends on how you have created OrbitBtn, did you create it using Scene editor? where you create them as gameobjects?? If so, click on the object to which you have added the above mentioned script, and see on your right side inspector window, you will see an object btnTexture1, so you drag and drop your OrbitBtn on top of it.

Comment: Thank you Karthik for your answer. I have tried what you advised, with no responce. The OrbitBtn is created in Scene editor as GUI Texture object. I have the script added on a 3d model.  What I want to achieve is,  to have the script run only when the button is touched. In the code above I can make this happen but with GUI.Button, not with GUI Texture. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do with GUI Texture?? GUI Button takes in a texture object which acts as a button??

Comment: I want to use a GUI Texture button instead of a coded GUI.Button, cause I have made an image that I'd like to use. I do not want to have the default GUI skin. Do you happen to know how to modify my posted code?

Comment: You can create custom gui skin, by creating a new skin. However, I am still not sure what you are trying to do, you want a image on a button?? then just use that image as the value for texture btnTexture1. If you want to use image as a button, then I will post a sample code soon

Comment: Hello again Karthik. I want to use an image (or a 3d model) as a button. OnTouch(android), it would run the posted script. It would be very welcome if you could post a working sample code.

Comment: I hope this helps you and if it did, mark the answer :)